# Вывести из списка фамилии которые встречаются в словаре

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть список содержащий фамилии людей и словарь имеющий информацию человека в виде фамилии и пола.
Нужно написать функцию которая будет перебирать фамилии из списка и если будет фамилия из словаря, то вывести, что эта фамилия есть в словаре, если нет, то спросить какого пола носитель фамилии и занести в словарь.
У меня есть словарь и список

```
stu = dict(Василенко="F", Нермов="M", Свистов="M", Морозов="M", Розмова="F", Шептунов="M", Канатов="F", Урмова="F", Фидотиев="M", Дорогиев="F")
```

```
s = []  
li = ['Нещенко', 'Ющенко', 'Нермов', 'Камюков', 'Романов', 'Дроздов', 'Урмова', 'Морозов', 'Тисков', 'Жнов', 'Фидотиев", "Саламанс", "Скверов", "Тихонюк", "Крымский"]
s
li
```

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы пытались решить задачу

Comment: Для решения посмотрите в сторону dict.keys(), dict.values()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in li:
    if i in stu:
        print(i, 'pass')
    else:
        s = input('{}, какой пол?'.format(i))
        stu.update({i: s})
print(stu)

>...
>Дроздов, какой пол?5
>Урмова pass
>Морозов pass
>Тисков, какой пол?6
>Жнов, какой пол?7
>...
```

> {'Василенко': '', 'Нермов': 'M', 'Свистов': 'M', 'Морозов': 'M',
> 'Розмова': '', 'Шептунов': 'M', 'Канатов': 'F', 'Урмова': 'F',
> 'Фидотиев': 'M', 'Дорогиев': 'F', 'Нещенко': '1', 'Ющенко': '2',
> 'Камюков': '3', 'Романов': '4', 'Дроздов': '5', 'Тисков': '6', 'Жнов':
> '7', 'Саламанс': '8', 'Скверов': '9', 'Тихонюк': '0', 'Крымский':
> '00'}

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!